# Set key,values for iteritem in for loop

Tags: jinja2

How can I iterate over the element `{{ dict.r0t0p1 }}` using the for-loops I have established?
The desired end result of the `<input..` line is next. In the example line the key is `r0t0p1`, and I need the corresponding value, where in this case the loop value of both r and t are 0, but they change for each input line.

`<input type="text"  id="r0t0p1"  name="r0t0p1" value="{{ dict.r0t0p1 }}"></input>`

So the same values of `r` and `t` for the id and the name attributes are required for the dict key to produce the dict value.

```
{% for r in range(rounds)%}
{% for t in range(tables)%}
    <input type="text"  id="r{{r}}t{{t}}p1"  name="r{{r}}t{{t}}p1" value="{{ dict.r0t0p1 }}"></input>
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

I tried using a set command to define `cell` but got the following error. So it looks like nesting loop indices won't work.

```
{% set cell = r{{r}}t{{t}}p1 %}
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'
```

Comment: You should use `value="{{ dict[r0t0p1] }}` and not `value="{{ dict.r0t0p1 }}`

Comment: If you want to set value to cell, do this `{% set cell = 'r'+r|string+'t'+t|string6+'p1' %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe:-

```
{% for r in range(rounds)%}
{% for t in range(tables)%}
{% set cell = 'r'+r|string+'t'+t|string+'p1' %}
    <input type="text"  id="{{ cell }}"  name="{{ cell }}" value="{{ dic[cell] }}"></input>
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Please notice I changed dict to dic.

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long to reply. My reason is that the flexbox style I am using seems to get destroyed by this change. Your `set` seems to work except that the resulting screen view is unusable and unrecognizable. When I look at the "elements" pane/tab in the DevTools I see different elements even at the coarsest level. Without any jinja I see only one div and it's named "main", but with jinja I also see the first sub-div under "main" but at the same level as "main". Tried with other browsers and same messed up view. Is there know problems with jinja colliding with CSS?

Comment: My bad. I found the problem. I left out an ending " in one place.